# Power BI / DAX - Distinct Counts in 2 Columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, dashboard

I've the following table and I need to get the following results. In few words, I think the Date column should be a distinct count as also the Item. However, I can't make it work in Power BI. I've tried different measures before.

```
ID |Date       |Item
______________________
123|01/Jan/2020|Apples
123|02/Jan/2020|Apples
123|03/Jan/2020|Apples
123|03/Jan/2020|Oranges
123|02/Jan/2020|Oranges
123|01/Jan/2020|Oranges
123|02/Jan/2020|Apples
123|01/Jan/2020|Apples
123|03/Jan/2020|Apples
123|02/Jan/2020|Apples
123|03/Jan/2020|Apples
123|01/Jan/2020|Apples

(...)
```

```
Results wanted:
_______________

Apples = 3
Oranges = 1
```

Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have Oranges for 3 different days. Why the count is 1 for oranges?

Comment: Yes: Apples = 3 and Oranges = 1. I have a long list with different IDs, dates and items. What I need to know is: for ID 123 I have 3 rows for oranges (days 1, 2 and 3), so I need to count oranges as 1 and for apples I have 9 rows (each 3 of them for days 1, 2 and 3) which means that I have to count apples as 3 times. And then repeat this process to the others IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand the the application or what you're doing, but it seems like you want to count instances of Apples or Oranges on some given date.

This would accomplish that by just counting instances of apple on a given date (drop the date filter if you're handling that on the visualization side)

```
Apples = CALCULATE(COUNT(table[Item]), table[Date]=DATE(2020,1,1), table[Item]="Apples")
```

Then the same thing for oranges...

Any extra details on what you're using this for might be valuable.

Comment: I have a long list with different IDs, dates and items. This with ID 123 was just an example. What I need to know is: for ID 123 I have 3 rows for oranges (days 1, 2 and 3), so I need to count oranges as 1 and for apples I have 9 rows (each 3 of them for days 1, 2 and 3) which means that I have to count apples as 3 times. And then repeat this process to the others IDs, dates and items. No filters can't be used inside the code because the selection is made through a dropdown list by ID.